# The Kills/Deaths/Assists and Last Hits/Denies not in correct position

Tags: dota-2

My Kills/Deaths/Assists and Last Hits/Denies is in the top right corner. I would like it to be below the basic courier controls (bring items, boost speed of courier). Please tell me where I go in the options to change this.

Comment: Hi @user91693, could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

These statistics are displayed in the upper right on 4:3 screen resolutions, as there is not enough room to display them in their normal locations. Some other UI elements, such as the store interface, are moved around as well.

[image: 4:3 example]

Switch to a 16:9 or 16:10 resolution to display these UI elements in their "normal" locations.

[image: 16:9 example]